# Multi directional parametric equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

> A particle in the $xy$-plane starts at the point $(1, 1)$ and moves along the curve $y = x^2$ to the point $(−1, 1)$ and then returns along the same curve to the point $(1, 1)$. Use a single vector-valued function to represent the path of the particle over a single interval (for the parameter). Don’t forget to give the interval for the parameter.

From what I understand, the x value starts at $1$, decreases to $-1$, and increases to $1$. One function that does this is cosine. So if I set $x = \cos(t)$, then
$y = \cos(t)^{2}$ (due to $y = x^2$). Further, the interval for the parameter is $[0, \pi]$. So then, the vector-valued function is $r(t) = \langle \cos(t), \cos(t)^2 \rangle$.

Is my understanding correct? I am kind of hesitant because of how straightforward this question was, and I'm worried that I'm missing something or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right except for the interval. You need the point to return to $(1,1)$, so the parameter should continue to increase to $2\pi$. The interval is $[0,2\pi]$.